# Combining two python scripts into one

Tags: python, regex

I am a Python beginner.

I have these two working scripts:

```py
import re

article_content = [open('input.txt').read() ]

split_article_content = []

for element in article_content:
    split_article_content += re.split("(?<=[.!:;?])\s+", element)

print(*split_article_content, sep='\n\n')
pbcopy
```

```py
with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    buff = []
    i = 1
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():  #skips the empty lines
           buff.append(line)
        if line.strip() == "<end>":
           output = open('/%d.txt' % i,'w')
           output.write(''.join(buff))
           output.close()
           i+=1
           buff = [] #buffer reset
```

The former makes each sentence a separate paragraph.
The latter splits the input into separate output .txt files based on (or after each) specified symbol `<end>`.

The one script that I need to execute is this:

- Make each sentence a separate paragraph `split_article_content` and split into separate output .txt files based on (after each) specified symbol `<end>` (**while keeping the separate paragraphs in the final output**).

To better illustrate:
**Input**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec congue metus in nisl mollis egestas. 

Aenean iaculis arcu turpis, at iaculis leo dapibus eget. Donec in lacus vel justo fermentum sagittis. Maecenas vel dui quis nisi placerat porta in ac justo. Etiam porttitor nisl tincidunt enim pretium, ac vulputate tortor ultricies. Pellentesque eros massa, volutpat ac iaculis vitae, elementum ac leo. Curabitur sodales enim mattis lectus lobortis lobortis. 
<end>
Integer sagittis, lorem sit amet ultricies commodo, libero mauris porttitor lacus, vel tincidunt nunc diam sit amet quam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut et egestas velit. 
Suspendisse posuere, ligula sed dapibus dictum, lorem tellus faucibus est, non tincidunt tortor elit ac lacus. Proin dictum turpis sed tortor efficitur, ut aliquet dolor pretium. 

Praesent ac tincidunt nunc. Maecenas pharetra odio in lectus mattis imperdiet. Nullam tellus orci, tincidunt non odio eget, imperdiet tempus metus. Cras faucibus turpis vel rutrum elementum. 

Proin ut venenatis arcu. Ut consectetur tellus at erat ullamcorper, ac convallis nibh suscipit. Donec viverra dui ac metus vestibulum, quis luctus neque maximus. 
<end>
Cras blandit commodo mattis. Suspendisse eget lacinia nibh, eu viverra eros. Ut tincidunt, sapien eu interdum pulvinar, mauris tortor molestie sem, nec pulvinar orci quam fringilla mauris.

Pellentesque viverra, sapien sed dapibus semper, erat mauris lobortis ante, ut tempus augue sem sed urna. Praesent sed dui nec nisi aliquam blandit et eget risus. Vivamus egestas nunc ut varius auctor. Suspendisse id laoreet nisi. Mauris lobortis molestie risus ac condimentum. Fusce velit purus, finibus in mollis ac, blandit sed ligula. Curabitur mauris nisi, scelerisque et ultricies eget, malesuada eu velit.
<end>
```

**1.txt output**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

Donec congue metus in nisl mollis egestas. 

Aenean iaculis arcu turpis, at iaculis leo dapibus eget. 

Donec in lacus vel justo fermentum sagittis. 

Maecenas vel dui quis nisi placerat porta in ac justo. 

Etiam porttitor nisl tincidunt enim pretium, ac vulputate tortor ultricies. 

Pellentesque eros massa, volutpat ac iaculis vitae, elementum ac leo. 

Curabitur sodales enim mattis lectus lobortis lobortis. 

<end>
```

**2.txt output**

```
Integer sagittis, lorem sit amet ultricies commodo, libero mauris porttitor lacus, vel tincidunt nunc diam sit amet quam. 

In hac habitasse platea dictumst. 

Ut et egestas velit. 

Suspendisse posuere, ligula sed dapibus dictum, lorem tellus faucibus est, non tincidunt tortor elit ac lacus. 

Proin dictum turpis sed tortor efficitur, ut aliquet dolor pretium.

Praesent ac tincidunt nunc. 

Maecenas pharetra odio in lectus mattis imperdiet. 

Nullam tellus orci, tincidunt non odio eget, imperdiet tempus metus. 

Cras faucibus turpis vel rutrum elementum. 

Proin ut venenatis arcu. 

Ut consectetur tellus at erat ullamcorper, ac convallis nibh suscipit. 

Donec viverra dui ac metus vestibulum, quis luctus neque maximus. 

<end>
```

... **etc.**

Best I could figure out:

```py
import re

with open("input.txt", "r") as f:

    split_article_content = []
    for element in f:
        split_article_content += re.split("(?<=[.!:;?])\s+", element)

    buff = []
    i = 1
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():  #skips the empty lines
            buff.append(line)
        if line.strip() == "<end>":
            output = open('%d.txt' % i,'w')
            output.write(''.join(buff))
            output.close()
            i+=1
            buff = [] #buffer reset
```

I seem to struggle with:

- keeping the separate paragraphs in the final output; or avoiding the latter part which separates the text to relapse back to output where paragraphs are not separated.
- the use of reg. expression `re` when trying to combine these.

I would like to learn how to do this.

Comment: Could you explain better what you want to achieve? "get these into one" is not clear. What is the expected input and output? How the two separate scripts work together? Which one do you execute first? Does the second one take the output of the first one as input?

Comment: Added more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```py
import re

with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    i = 1
    w = None
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            if line == "<end>":
                if w is not None:
                    w.close()
                    i += 1
                    w = None
            else:
                if w is None:
                    w = open('output%i.txt' % i, 'w')
                for s in re.split("(?<=[.!:;?])\s+", line):
                    w.write(s + '\n\n')
```

Another version closer to your own attempt:

```py
with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    split_article_content = []
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            split_article_content += re.split("(?<=[.!:;?])\s+", line)  
    buff = []
    i = 1
    for sentence in split_article_content:
        if sentence == "<end>":
            output = open('%d.txt' % i,'w')
            output.write('\n\n'.join(buff))
            output.close()
            i += 1
            buff = []
        else:    
            buff.append(sentence)
```

Comment: So far this works. My larger inputs still don‘t work, but that may be a formatting issue. I‘ll update soon.

Comment: Both seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your first script rather weirdly creates a single-element list and then loops over that lone element.

Your final attempt doesn't seem to do anything with the split sentences.

```py
import re

i = 0
with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    w = open('output%i.txt' % i, 'w')
    for line in f:

        if line == '<end>\n':
            w.write(line)
            w.close()
            i += 1
            w = None
            continue

        for sent in re.split("(?<=[.!:;?])\s+", line):
            if w is None:
                w = open('output%i.txt' % i, 'w')
            w.write(sent + '\n')
```

We read a line at a time, and if it's `<end>` we close the current file; if not, we split into sentences, and write out each.

We avoid opening a new file after we closed the previous output file until we see that there is more data to write, which slightly complicates the script.

Looping over the elements and writing them out as we encounter them obviates the need to keep intermediate results in memory, and simplifes the flow.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Updated slightly, but the code should really speak for itself. If it's still unclear, can you point to anything in particular which requires explanation? The `continue` statement terminates the current iteration, so there is no need for an explicit `else:` after it.

Comment: @SimonAnte Does it work?

Comment: @MikeM Can‘t figure this out. Either not working or getting .txt outputs without split sentences. I‘ll post updates soon.

Comment: Using the above-mentioned input example, I get seperate files (good) but there still seems to be an issue with sentence splitting. Also, I have much larger txt inputs where even the file splitting by `<end>` doesn't seem to work. Maybe just formating?